# What's wrong with this Binary Search function?

Tags: c, binary-search

I am tring to solve a Spoj problems of Binary Search but I keep getting "wrong answer" and I can't see my problem.
Here is my bsearch function:

```
int binarySearch(int numbers[], int size, int key)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = size - 1;
    int middle;

    while(start <= end)
    {
        middle = start + (end - start)/2;

        if(key < numbers[middle])
            end = middle - 1;
        else if(key > numbers[middle])
            start = middle + 1;
        else
            return middle;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

And this is my main function

```
int main()
{
    int *numbers;
    int n_numbers, n_queries, key, i, found;

    scanf("%d %d", &n_numbers, &n_queries);
    numbers = (int*)malloc(n_numbers * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i<n_numbers; i++)
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);

    for(i = 0; i<n_queries; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &key);
        found = binarySearch(numbers, n_numbers, key);
        printf("%d\n", found);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the SPOJ problem:
http://www.spoj.com/problems/BSEARCH1/

Comment: Seems correct.Can you give example input/output?

Comment: in order to make it work, you must sort the array you are binary-searching

Comment: Spoj doesn't give the test cases, so I don't know why it say it's wrong

Comment: @J0rge: You could at least add a lin to the SPOJ problem.

Comment: It is wrong because the data you are passing in isn't sorted.  You must sort the data Spoj / the client provides.  Then run binary search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are required to return the location of the *first* occurrence (starting from zero), and you are returning as soon as you find the key.

But it's possible that the array is:
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2

And the key is 1. You should return 1 (the location of the first occurence) and instead you are returning 6.

Comment: Just a quick note for your next question: If you ask about SPOJ, add a link to the problem, and in any case at least copy the complete description. I had to follow the link provided by Zeta to find out that you're supposed to return the first occurrence (and not any occurrence).

Comment: Ok, sorry for this one. I will edit my question for someone who might need help

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is correct.  The data is not sorted, so you binary search algorithm cannot correctly zero in on the solution.

Comment: It's probably this problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/BSEARCH1/. If the caller doesn't provide sorted data the bsearch is quite useless.

Comment: @Zeta yes, most definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear which C based language you are using but might the expression (end - start)/2 possibly return a floating point value that is then truncated to an integer when you actually would want the value rounded?

Comment: it is the lack of sorted data.  Notice how OP assumes data will be sorted, this is not a guarantee.